# How to define global variable in class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, global-variables

I want to take a variable outside the class but not outside of the file. I have a condition outside the class but I have to use it in the class too. Have can i do that?

This is the sample to try if it is working. I want to erase the input part and do with global variable.

```
class ComplexMethods:
    ask = input("What type you are writing? (absolute value and phase angle or real and imaginary parts)")
    if ask == "real and imaginary parts":
```

I tried this one but not working. It gives name "ask" not defined.

```
class ComplexMethods:
     global ask
     if ask == "real and imaginary parts":
```

This is the outside of class.

```
ask = input("What type you are writing? (absolute value and phase angle or real and imaginary parts)")
if ask == "real and imaginary parts":
    firstcomplexreal = float(input("Enter real part of first complex number: "))
    firstcompleximaginary = float(input("Enter imaginary part of first complex number: "))
    secondcomplexreal = float(input("Enter real part of second complex number: "))
    secondcompleximaginary = float(input("Enter imaginary part of second complex number: "))
    complexnumbers = ComplexMethods(firstcomplexreal, firstcompleximaginary, secondcomplexreal,
                                    secondcompleximaginary)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Global variables are generally a bad idea.

Comment: Why are you doing any of that in a class definition?

Comment: The `if` statement is being executed when you define the class, not when you create instances of it. That means you have to assign the variable before you define the class.

Comment: I want to try it and it doing different things in class, so I need to use global variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to define your variable outside of the class you don't need to use the `global` keyword unless you plan on modifying it. If you just want to read the variable and not modify it you could just do something like.

```
ask = input("What type you are writing? (absolute value and phase angle or real and imaginary parts)")

class ComplexMethods:
    if ask == "real and imaginary parts":
        pass

if ask == "real and imaginary parts":
    firstcomplexreal = float(input("Enter real part of first complex number: "))
    firstcompleximaginary = float(input("Enter imaginary part of first complex number: "))
    secondcomplexreal = float(input("Enter real part of second complex number: "))
    secondcompleximaginary = float(input("Enter imaginary part of second complex number: "))
    complexnumbers = ComplexMethods(firstcomplexreal, firstcompleximaginary, secondcomplexreal,
                                    secondcompleximaginary)
```

Comment: Fix your indentation please

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do but perhaps you just need to have
`global ask`
above your 
`ask=input("")` outside the class.

Comment: I want to replace ask=input("") to global ask. For not taking input again.

Comment: `global` doesn't do anything if it's not inside a function.

Comment: Jim, you can use the comments on the question to ask for more information if you're not yet sure what the question is about.

Comment: Sure thing Dennis Kuypers.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Thank you from Barmar. It worked.

```
ask = input("What type you are writing? (absolute value and phase angle or real and imaginary parts)")


class ComplexMethods:
    global ask
    if ask == "real and imaginary parts":
```

Answer (score 0):

if you're referring to a static, something available from `Class.val` and `instance.val` referencing the same thing; you can declare one in the class body

```
class A:
  val = None # Static variable
  def __init__(self, x, y):
    # Instance variables
    self.x = x
    self.y = y

inst_1 = A(2, 3)
inst_2 = A("a", "b")

print(A.val)
# static can't be modified via instance, only A
A.val = "abcd"
print(inst_2.val) # static modified across As

# Unique to each instance
print(inst_1.x)
print(inst_2.x)
```